# Search filter on listview returns wrong position on item click

Tags: android, baseadapter

I have listview   and after filtering items of listview  when I click on item its always returning wrong position of listview item.

Following is Adapter Class:

```
public class AdmitPatientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> TempArrList = new ArrayList<>();
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
public static final String TAG_MRDNO = "mrd_no";


public AdmitPatientAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data = d;
    TempArrList.addAll(d);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


}


public int getCount() {
    return TempArrList.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    TempArrList.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        TempArrList.addAll(data);

    } else {
        HashMap<String, String> tMap;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            tMap = data.get(i);
            if (charText.length() != 0 && tMap.get("mrd_no").toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {//mrd_no
                TempArrList.add(tMap);
            } else if (charText.length() != 0 && tMap.get("pname").toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {//pname
                TempArrList.add(tMap);
            } else if (charText.length() != 0 && tMap.get("bed_no").toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                TempArrList.add(tMap);
            } else if (charText.length() != 0 && tMap.get("nursingstation").toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                TempArrList.add(tMap);
            }

        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View viw = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        viw = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ip_ptn_items, null);
    TextView txt_Mr_dno = (TextView) viw.findViewById(R.id.txtMrdno);
    TextView txt_pitnt_Name = (TextView) viw.findViewById(R.id.txtpitntName);
    TextView txt_Bed_no = (TextView) viw.findViewById(R.id.txtBedno);
    TextView txt_Dob = (TextView) viw.findViewById(R.id.txtDob);

    TextView txt_drNme = (TextView) viw.findViewById(R.id.txtDr);
    TextView txt_Sex = (TextView) viw.findViewById(R.id.txtSex);
    TextView txt_Wrdnm = (TextView) viw.findViewById(R.id.txtWrdnm);

    HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
    item = TempArrList.get(position);
    String mrd_no = item.get(TAG_MRDNO);
    item.put(TAG_MRDNO, mrd_no);
    mrd_no = item.get(TAG_MRDNO);

    if (mrd_no.endsWith("*")) {
        txt_Mr_dno.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        txt_pitnt_Name.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        txt_Dob.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        txt_Sex.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        txt_Wrdnm.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        txt_Bed_no.setTextColor(Color.RED);


    } else {
        txt_Mr_dno.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        txt_pitnt_Name.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        txt_Dob.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        txt_Sex.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        txt_Wrdnm.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        txt_Bed_no.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

    }

    //Setting all values in listview
    txt_Mr_dno.setText(item.get("mrd_no"));
    txt_pitnt_Name.setText(item.get("pname"));
    txt_Bed_no.setText(item.get("bed_no"));
    txt_Dob.setText(item.get("dob"));
    //txt_admit_Date.setText(item.get("admission_date"));
    txt_Sex.setText(item.get("sex"));
    txt_Wrdnm.setText(item.get("nursingstation"));
    txt_drNme.setText(item.get("doctor"));


    //  item = data.get(position);
    ///  String userType = item.get(TAG_UTYPE);
    //  item.put(TAG_UTYPE, mrd_no);
    //  userType = item.get(TAG_UTYPE);

    try {
        if (item.get("userType").equals("doctor")) {
            txt_drNme.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            txt_drNme.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return viw;

}


}
```

and another one is on click event class:

```
public class AdmitPatientFragment extends Fragment implements FragmentCycle {


ListView lstViw;
AdmitPatientAdapter adapter;
String DcId = "";
String userType = "";
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;


// generic array list
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dlst = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

// json url
private static String url = "http://scanweb.dmhospital.org:81/amrita_login/AdmList.php?auth=Yes";


@Override
public void onResumeFragment() {

}

@Override
public void onPauseFragment() {

}


// json node names
private static final String TAG_ADMITLIST = "AdmissionList";
private static final String TAG_MRD = "mrd_no";
private static final String TAG_PNAME = "pname";
private static final String TAG_BNO = "bed_no";
private static final String TAG_DOB = "dob";
private static final String TAG_ADMIT_DATE = "admission_date";
private static final String TAG_DOCTOR = "doctor";
private static String TAG_SEX = "sex";
private static String TAG_PATN_ID = "patient_id";
private static String TAG_VISIT_ID = "visit_id";
private static final String TAG_WARD_NAME = "nursingstation";
public static final String TAG_UTYPE = "userType";

JSONArray AdmissionList = null;

public AdmitPatientFragment() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    setReturnTransition(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    LinearLayout rootView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.ip_ptn_lstviw, container, false);

    dlst = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    DcId = intent.getStringExtra("drid");


    if (CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(getActivity())) //returns true if internet available
    {


    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    // to read doctor id from shared preferences
    sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    DcId = sharedPreferences.getString("drid", DcId);
    userType = sharedPreferences.getString("usertype", userType);

    url = url + "&docID=" + DcId;

    new paAsyncTask().execute();


    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.three_dots_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    //*** setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener ***
    searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

        }
    });

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String searchQuery) {
            adapter.filter(searchQuery.toString().trim());
            lstViw.invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    });

    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            // Do something when collapsed
            return true;  // Return true to collapse action view
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            // Do something when expanded
            return true;  // Return true to expand action view
        }
    });

}


private class paAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        try {
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait admit patient list is loading ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

        pDialog.dismiss();

        try {
            // Getting JSON Array from URL
            AdmissionList = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ADMITLIST);
            dlst = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < AdmissionList.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = AdmissionList.getJSONObject(i);

                String admission_date = c.getString(TAG_ADMIT_DATE);


                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                String ageSex = "(" + c.getString(TAG_DOB) + " | " + c.getString(TAG_SEX) + ")";

                String[] admDte = admission_date.split(":");
                String[] admDte1 = admission_date.split(":");


                String resultDte = admDte[0] + ":" + admDte1[1];

                map.put(TAG_MRD, c.getString(TAG_MRD).toString());
                map.put(TAG_PNAME, c.getString(TAG_PNAME));
                map.put(TAG_BNO, c.getString(TAG_BNO));

                map.put(TAG_DOB, ageSex);
                map.put(TAG_ADMIT_DATE, resultDte);
                map.put(TAG_UTYPE, userType);
                map.put(TAG_DOCTOR, c.getString(TAG_DOCTOR).toString());
                // map.put(TAG_SEX, str);
                map.put(TAG_WARD_NAME, c.getString(TAG_WARD_NAME));
                map.put(TAG_PATN_ID, c.getString(TAG_PATN_ID));
                map.put(TAG_VISIT_ID, c.getString(TAG_VISIT_ID));


                dlst.add(map);
            }

            lstViw = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lstAdmsion);
            adapter = new AdmitPatientAdapter(getActivity(), dlst);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            lstViw.setAdapter(adapter);


            lstViw.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                        View view, int position, long id) {

                    HashMap<String, String> map = dlst.get(position);
                    Intent imp = new Intent(getActivity(),
                            NavigationDrawerActivity.class);
                    imp.putExtra("drid", DcId);
                    //  imp.putExtra(TAG_ADMIT_DATE, map.get(""));
                    imp.putExtra("docNme", map.get(TAG_DOCTOR));
                    imp.putExtra("ptnId", map.get(TAG_PATN_ID));
                    imp.putExtra("vst_id", map.get(TAG_VISIT_ID));

                    startActivity(imp);
                }
            });
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: why dont you use an `ArrayAdapter` instead of custom `BaseAdapter`?

Comment: @pskink cant we continue using BaseAdapter and thanks for rply

Comment: you can continue but why to make your life harder if you can use more simple solutions?

Comment: @pskink I thought it would be good to use

Comment: I need to change just line of code but im nt getting where should i do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
HashMap<String, String> map = dlst.get(position);
```

to

```
HashMap<String, String> map = adapter.getItem(position);
```

Basically, the OnItemClickListener is grabbing objects from your ListView rather than your Adapter that has updated references...

EDIT 1: You also need to implement getItem in your Adapter so it returns an object from your filtered list. I'm assuming that's dlst...

So, you would need to put this in your adapter class:

```
public HashMap<String, String>  getItem(int position){
    return dlst.get(position);
}
```

Comment: You need to manage with Custom Object or with new adapter and data.

Comment: @shobhik I tried but its saying error: cannot find symbol method get(int)
how can I remove it and thanks for rply

Comment: Sorry, I meant getItem(int)

Comment: Updating my answer

Comment: @shobhik I did it what u said but after doing this public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  getItem(int position){
    return dlst.get(position);
} I am getting compile time error  at the adapter side 
Error:(49, 24) error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> also error at the side of on item click method Error:(249, 70) error: incompatible types: ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> cannot be converted to HashMap<String,String>

Comment: Sorry, I was super distracted. Meant to return the Hashmap, not the ArrayList of Hashmaps! Edited answer.

Comment: @shobhik I solved this problem man just I am changed getItem method like  public Object getItem(int position) {
        return TempArrList.get(position);
    }  and I did casting of adapter class  in side the onItemClick event and thank u vry much for help

Comment: Happy I could help!

Comment: Your Edit 1 is exactly what i was looking for ! .. thanks